# Asset Bundle is not visible from Spectator perspective

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mr-spectatorview

I follow the tutorial correctly and I was able to setup spectator view and build the application without any problems. Here is the flow of how my application goes:

- I download an Asset Bundle and instantiate it as an Gameobject.
- I put the GameObject under the Broadcaster Gameobject in the SpectatorView.
- I attach a Bounding Box from MRTK V2 Library to the instantiated Gameobject.
- I also attach a box to the asset bundle (as a child game object). Clicking the Asset Bundle toggle the visibility of the box.
- I build the application.

Of course I input the IP Address of user to both of User and Spectator.

On the user side, the Gameobject (Assetbundle), the bounding box and the attached child box is visible.

From the Spectator side, the Gameobject (Assetbundle) is not visible, but the bounding box and the child box is clearly visible. Of course my interaction with the Assetbundle is visible from the Spectator (moving, scaling).

Is this the library problem? I asked the [Spectator View Github Page](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/issues/301) the other day, but I got no answer yet.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I used two Hololens (User and Spectator) in this scenario.

Comment: I've added some comments to your github post.

I don't think the scenario you are describing is currently supported by spectator view. Are you currently creating the Assetbundle or are you obtaining it from somewhere else?

Comment: hey @chrisfromwork, thank you for your answer. I create my own Assetbundle and upload it to my own server. then, the other application will download the Assetbundle and unload it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this [step](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/master/doc/SpectatorView.Setup.md#building--deploying) in the Spectator View Mobile Setup:

> In the Unity editor, call 'Spectator View -> Update All Asset Caches' (This will be located in the Unity editor toolbar) to prepare content for state synchronization. Add the Generated.StateSynchronization.AssetCaches folder to your project's repository to share across development devices.

You need to generate and check-in Asset Caches to your the HoloLens and spectator applications. These Asset Caches act as GameObject registries and will allow different devices running your application to understand what Unity GameObjects are being created, destroyed and updated throughout the application life cycle.

Besides, adding, updating and removing assets will require **updating these asset caches** as well as re-compiling each platform. (Please see: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-SpectatorView/blob/master/src/SpectatorView.Unity/Assets/SpectatorView/Scripts/StateSynchronization/README.md)

Comment: So in conclusion, sharing Assetbundle through Spectator View is not yet supported in the runtime/deployment?

Comment: No, it is not a supported scenario. You could try and package the Asset cache into your asset bundle, hand the asset bundle from the hololens to the spectator view device and then use this to synchronize your experience. Setting this up seems non-trivial but feasible.